# page displays white screen

Tags: jsf-2

When I open a JSF page from the menu and trying to navigate to next page, but it shows a blank (white) screen. If I open another page using other menus then the previous page is displayed (I mean the first one). Can somebody let me know whether any configuration is provided by  JSF2.0, because it was working fine with the previous versions of JSF (1.1 and 1.2)?

Comment: Can you post some code, so we can see how your navigation looks like?

Comment: we have a kind of workflows through which we will navigate the pages, for me iam able to see the first 2 pages properly when the navigation comes to the 3rd page it is going blank(white screen appears).... if u open any other page or do some other activity .. then it displays the page properly.

Comment: Well it's hard to guess :-) If it mostly works except in one scenario, post code relevant to that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you rightclick and choose view source what do you see? If you see JSF tags it did not pass through FacesServlet and thus no html will be created and white page might occur.

You need to google up faces-config should look like and you need to make sure you have the facesServlet configured correctly in web.xml.

Here's mine from a little project that works but I can't guarantee it's correct

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">

    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>sv</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>sv_FI</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>en_GB</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>sv</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>


</application>
</faces-config>
```

Comment: Hi Karl Kilden, Thanks for your quick answer. but my faces-config.xml is fine and when i see my jsf page viewsource it is not showning that page details instead it is displaying the parent page i.e. my home page.